# Haskell Pre-order Traversal Tree to List

Tags: haskell, tree, traversal, preorder

I am having trouble getting my code to do a preorder traversal of a tree to a list to work. The definition for the tree is as follows:

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
          | Leaf a
```

and my definition for preorder traversal is as follows:

```
preorder  :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
preorder f g (Leaf b) = [g b]
preorder f g (Branch a left right) = [f a] ++ preorder f g left ++ preorder f g right
```

However the error I am getting is:

```
Couldn't match type `b' with `a'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
In the first argument of `f', namely `a'
In the expression: f a
In the first argument of `(++)', namely `[f a]'
```

I know my problem is the type of the first argument of that function and how it needs to be of type [c] but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get that. I have tried all combinations of brackets around the f a and no brackets and none give me a successful run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your types or function calls mixed up - probably the types, given the way you've named your variables.

You've said that `Tree a b` has a `b` in its first argument, but the `f` argument to `preorder` takes an `a`. Similarly `Leaf` takes an `a` but you're calling `g` on it, which takes a `b`.

That's what the error message is telling you: the first argument you passed to `f` is of type `b`, when it expected an `a`.

If you change your datatype to:

```
data Tree a b = Branch a (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
              | Leaf b
```

Then your code compiles fine.

Alternatively change `preorder` to

```
preorder  :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
preorder f g (Leaf a) = [f a]
preorder f g (Branch b left right) = [g b] ++ preorder f g left ++ preorder f g right
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize I had flipped them I am fairly new to haskell